# APP freeze when i start it using notification pending intent in nadroid

Tags: xamarin.android, urhosharp

so I'm using UrhoSharp 1.5.22 and its work perfectly but when i send notification using notification manager and try to click it, the app freeze with white blank page without throwing exception....i even try to put break point and it didn't work ether ... in earlier use of urho 1.1.214 this problem doesn't appear but i don't think i can take instance from Urho Application class that control the scene .
my code of Surface creation is:

```
var mLayout = FindViewById<AbsoluteLayout>(Resource.Id.absoluteLayout1);
var surface = UrhoSurface.CreateSurface(this);
mLayout.AddView(surface);
var app = await surface.Show<MyScene>(null, false);
```

and for notification :

```
var nMgr = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
var notification = new Notification(ico, "blablabla");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent,0);
notification.SetLatestEventInfo(this, "blablabla", newnot, pendingIntent);
nMgr.Notify((int)NotificationFlags.ForegroundService, notification);

ActivityFlags.NewTask neded because i need to start the app from Service
```

// ============== if it was a bug in urho release please let me no if i can take the instance in 1.1.2.14 release for example or it will be fixed in the next version.
thanks .

edit: I'm trying to open the activity from BGService

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `ActivityFlags` from :

```
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
```

To :

```
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
```

Comment: thanks for answering . already try it and didn't work ... worked only in 1.1.2.14 release

Comment: @Ibrahimwahbi, I test it on version `1.7.3` and `1.5.2` and both works fine on myside. Here is sample [urho-samples/SamplyGame](https://github.com/xamarin/urho-samples/tree/master/SamplyGame) I use.

Comment: @Ibrahimwahbi,  would you mind share a basic demo to reproduce this problem, to make sure we are verifying the exact same thing you are using.

Comment: Shen -MSFT sorry i forget to mansion put I'm trying to open the activity from BG Service  .. thats alink for ademo project just put the resource folder in mobile internal storage directly. https://www.dropbox.com/s/mfbk52rspe9myn5/urho_try.rar?dl=0